# How to get Custom Object Metadata CreatedBy

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, tooling-api

I need to get list of `Custom Objects` in a Salesforce org and find `Created By User` of each of them (`Created By` of object, *not* the records) .

Is it possible? I can get string list of custom objects as follows:

```
List<String> CustomObjectsList  = new List<String>();
List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();  
for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
{
    if (f.getDescribe().isCustom()){
        CustomObjectsList.add(f.getDescribe().getName());
    }
}
```

Now I need to find object creator of each (**not record creator**).

Comment: ChamingaD, could you be more specific about what you're trying to do and what isn't working for you ?  Are you doing this from apex,reports, api,.. ? Consider that providing more information in a question will lead to better answers.

Comment: If I'm not getting your question wrong, the answer is trivial, and you should use google instead of asking question.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Is there any way to get CreatedByUser of Custom Object in Salesforce ?

Comment: @BartJuriewicz Google didn't help. I need to query createdby field of a custom object (not created by in object records).

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question then.

Comment: @BartJuriewicz Is there anyway to get it ? Schema does not provide that info.

Comment: Are you still an active user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of `API Version 33.0`, you can query `CreatedBy` information via the `Tooling API`. **Queries including this field and using `API Version 32.0` or below will fail.**

```
SELECT CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, DeveloperName FROM CustomObject
```

[image: Query Editor (Use Tooling API)]

---

And since you asked how to do it via `Apex`, you can hit the `Tooling API` from `Apex` as follows:

```
public static Map<SObjectType, Id> getCustomObjectCreatedBy()
{
    String query = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(
        'SELECT CreatedById, DeveloperName FROM CustomObject', 'UTF-8'
    );
    String endpoint = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +
        '/services/data/v33.0/tooling/query?q=' + query;

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    String response = new Http().send(request).getBody();
    Map<String, Object> payload = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);

    Map<String, SObjectType> sObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Map<SObjectType, Id> output = new Map<SObjectType, Id>();
    for (Object data : (List<Object>)payload.get('records'))
    {
        Map<String, Object> record = (Map<String, Object>)data;
        String developerName = (String)record.get('DeveloperName');
        String createdById = (String)record.get('CreatedById');
        output.put(sObjects.get(developerName), createdById);
    }
    return output;
}
```

I cached the global describe because it makes this snippet run about 7x faster in my sandbox. It's still not exactly fast...This snippet takes about a half second to run.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This answer is outdated,the solution is posted in [Adrian's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/138968/119).
No, I don't think so. While you can use Schema to describe the field, i'm not sure how to get the actual data.

```
System.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Vehicle__C.fields.createdBy); //does work
```

I would  imagine this info to be available through the Metadata or Tooling API, and neither include the field in their Custom Object type documentation either.

[customObject in the Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/) , [customObject in the Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/index_Left.htm)

This usually means it's not available from apex either.

Comment: Fun fact, it was introduced in Version 33. Looks like that was Spring 15, released just a couple weeks after you posted this. Yay. It doesn't look like they included any mention of it in the [Release Notes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring15_release_notes.pdf), though they do mention many new fields available to the `Tooling API`.