# List all standard and custom fields for a given object (standard/custom object)

Tags: custom-field, sobject, standard-field

is there a way to list all the fields both standard and custom for a given  object.

tooling api - customfield gives only list of custom fields but not the standard fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use describes.

```
List<SObjectField> allFields = SObjectType.My_Object__c.fields.getMap().values();
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the lastmodified date of the custom field ?

Comment: @ab0369 That is a different question which has been answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/64797/2995) (just replace `CreatedBy` with `LastModifiedBy`). You need to use the `Tooling API` for that. You will have to use an endpoint/class with API Version >= 33.0.

Answer (score 1):

For API services, you can call either the REST describe call or SOAP describe call.

## REST

```
/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/describe
```

## SOAP

```
client.describeSObject("Account")
```

---

The Developer Console actually has a third option. Click on File > Open Resource, and type in the object's name, such as `Account.obj` or `Loan__c.obj`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the lastmodified date of the custom field ?