# Create new Visualforce page dynamically

Tags: visualforce, metadata-api, dynamic-visualforce

I want to define and create a new VF page dynamically, in Javascript or Apex (or whatever I can use). Is this possible at all? If so what technology allows this (e.g. Metadata API) and is there a sample somewhere I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `Tooling API` in order to achieve that. There is a lot of documentation around that, please check [this link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf).

Few examples can be found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/intro_rest_overview.htm) and [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/Content/intro_soap_overview.htm).

Also, there is already a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/how-do-i-use-the-tooling-api-to-create-a-new-apex-trigger) posted on this site.

Comment: @user1936026 This may be helpful. Just found in Google search: http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/force-com-tooling-api-create-apex-class-apex-trigger-dynamically-and-updatedelete-apex-trigger-apex-class-using-tooling-api-with-rest-api/

Comment: @regal Wow that's amazing! Great find. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I am now able to create the VF page in Apex. But how do I set its security settings? I have looked through the API Guide and haven't found anything useful.