# Tooling API - unable to figure out how create method is invoked

Tags: force.com, tooling-api

I am trying to understand tooling API - SOAP and was trying to create a simple Java class which uses tooling wsdl file to create Apex class. I borrowed the snippet from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_soap_overview.htm

but I am unable to figure out which object needs to be invoked to utilize create method to create new classes:
// call create() to add the class
SaveResult[] saveResults = sforce.create(classes);

I tried creating SforceService sforce; but it seems to be not available. I have included wsc-22.jar and created enterprise.jar from enterprise wsdl, toolingApi.jar from tooling wsdl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the Tooling API to create a new Apex Trigger?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/how-do-i-use-the-tooling-api-to-create-a-new-apex-trigger)

Comment: I know the duplicate is for a trigger but there is discussion in there for Apexclass as well. Maybe it will be useful

Comment: Or more appropriately: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/tooling-api-usage-in-salesforce-apex-method/15861#15861

Comment: Hi Eric Thanks for the response, I had gone through these post, but they are specific to Tooling API using REST. I am having no issues with using REST implementation but facing roadblock with SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tooling API via SOAP then `public SaveResult[] create(SObject[] sObjects)` method lives in `com.sforce.soap.tooling.ToolingConnection class`.

If you do not see it then this may relate to the ancient version of wsc (v22) you used or old version of Tooling WSDL.

NOTE:
not sure if it has been fixed in the current Tooling API (v34), but in the past in order to use `com.sforce.soap.tooling.ToolingConnection` you had to establish Enterprise (or Partner) SOAP connection first and then use returned session Id and endpoint (adjusted for tooling API) to call Tooling API via ToolingConnection.